# Unable to Drawtext using FFmpeg on a Video

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I am trying to use FFmpeg for text overlaying on video using '[ffmpeg-android-java](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java)'. The command I using like that:

```
command = "ffmpeg -i /storage/emulated/0/GsrVideo/testvideo.mp4 -vf drawtext=\"font=/storage/emulated/0/font/Pacifico.ttf:fontsize=20:fontcolor=red:x=10:y=10:text='hello'\" /storage/emulated/0/GsrVideo/editedVideo.mp4"
```

But it is giving error saying - **Error initializing filter 'drawtext' with args ""font=/storage/emulated/0/font/Pacifico.ttf:fontsize=20:fontcolor=red:x=10:y=10:text='hello'", Error opening filter!**

Please anyone can help me pointing out the problem in the filter.

Comment: It is just a typing mistake in posting the question. It is "drawtext" in code.